# Javascript open and hide radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A little problem that anyone but me can solve with ignorance of JS.
I open various divs after clicking on the payment method, according to the frequency of payments. I also open a div with text inputs.
The problem is that the used JS is applied to everything. So if by input (radio) unpack the div, another independent input (radio) closes it.
Also, if I unpack a div with other radio inputs by input, clicking on any of the divs will close the div again.

Here fiddle - [jsfiddle.net/72jzy8gb](http://jsfiddle.net/72jzy8gb)

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
                $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() { 
                    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value"); 
                    var targetBox = $("." + inputValue); 
                    $(".ukaz").not(targetBox).hide(); 
                    $(targetBox).show(); 
                }); 
            });
```

```css
.ukaz {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-daruj" action="https://www.darujme.cz/darovat/1320" id="myForm" method="get">
<table class="daruj-form">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;font-size:25px;">
<b style="color:#dd4814;">Částka dobrovolného příspěvku</b><br />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:-webkit-right;"><div style="width:147px;" id="castka">
<input name="amount" type="number" style="width: 100px;" value="100"> <span style="display:inline;">Kč</span></div><br /><input name="currency" type="hidden" value="CZK">
<input name="locale" type="hidden" value="cs"></td>

<td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:-webkit-left;"><div class="castky" style="
    margin-top: 6px;"><input type="radio" name="frequency" value="once"><div id="jednorazove" style="font-size:13px;color:black;font-weight:bold;display: inline;padding-left: 5px;vertical-align: super;">Jednorázově</div><br>
<input type="radio" name="frequency" value="monthly"> <div id="mesicne" style="padding-left:2px;font-size:13px;color:black;font-weight:bold;display: inline;vertical-align: super;"> Měsíčně</div></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:50%;">  
<input name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="Jméno"><br> 
<input name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Příjmení"><br> 
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Váš email"><br>   
<input name="phone" type="number" placeholder="Telefonní číslo"><br>  
<br>
<b>Požadujete potvrzení o daru?</b><br>
<input type="radio" name="wantDonationCertificate" value="1" nazev="adresa"> Ano<br>
<input type="radio" name="wantDonationCertificate" value="0" checked=""> Ne<br>
</td>
<td><div class="1 ukaz">
<input name="street" type="text" placeholder="Ulice a číslo popisné"><br>
<input name="city" type="text" placeholder="Obec/město"><br>
<input name="postcode" type="text" placeholder="PSČ"><br>
</div>

<br>

<div class="once ukaz">
<b>Výběr platby:</b><br>
<input type="radio" name="paymentMethod" value="proxypay_charge"> Platba kartou<br>
<input type="radio" name="paymentMethod" value="funds_transfer"> Platba převodem<br>
<input type="radio" name="paymentMethod" value="payu_transfer"> Online platba PayU
</div>


<div class="monthly ukaz">
<b>Výběr platby:</b><br>
<input type="radio" name="paymentMethod" value="proxypay_charge"> Platba kartou<br>
<input type="radio" name="paymentMethod" value="funds_transfer"> Platba převodem
</div>
<b>Chcete zasílat aktuality na email?</b><br>
<input type="radio" name="custom[souhlas_se_zasilanim_novinek_svobody_zvirat_a_se_zpracovanim_osobnich_udaju_pro_tyto_ucely]" value="1" checked=""> Ano<br>
<input type="radio" name="custom[souhlas_se_zasilanim_novinek_svobody_zvirat_a_se_zpracovanim_osobnich_udaju_pro_tyto_ucely]" value="0"> Ne<br>

<input type="submit" value="Odeslat"> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

This is undesirable behavior.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Your text is a bit confusing, try to split it into separate points to make it easier to follow and understand.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an indicator that points on a specific element but not a group of elements.

I used a `name` of input instead of a `type` here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('input[name="wantDonationCertificate"]').click(function() {
  var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
  var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
  $(".ukaz").not(targetBox).hide();
  $(targetBox).show();
 });
});
```

Comment: But if I´ll use this code, other inputs they are closing anyway

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate a desired behaviour?

Comment: Okay. If I click on input value="once", open div "once ukaz". If I click on input value="monthly", hide "once ukaz" and show "monthly ukaz" .. Its OK.

But if I click on one of inputs in div, it close. One of variant must be visible all time. And next problem is: name="wantDonationCertificate" close divs "once ukaz" and "monthly ukaz"

Comment: @Milan could you try `input[name="frequency"]` and tell me if it help.

Comment: its better! But now input  name="wantDonationCertificate" not open div "1 ukaz" if value of  input is "1".

Comment: It will be better if you create a function to every input groups. And only then minimise them to one function. Does it make sense?

Comment: Probably yes, unfortunately I can not create javascript :(

Comment: I don't know all conditions of the form to create full code to you. But you can copy and edit function that I put in answer and change name according to input group. Then change rule that show/hide tags.

Comment: I added comments in fiddle for better understanding.

Comment: I looked at a link in your question and the code is the same.